# What is jQuery DataTables data amount limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In other words, what amount of data can I pass to it.

I'm used to server side pagination and I know that if I have let's say 10000 rows in a table and I want to display it, I will only get chunks of my data from the server and display those to the browser.

Can I get all my data in one shot and just pass it to jquery datatables and forget about server side implemented pagination and server side implemented row sorting ?

I hope I was clear enough asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. If using v1.9 you need to use [sAjaxSource](http://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sAjaxSource) in the datatables initialisation, but don't enable `bServerSide` (server side processing). The v.1.10 equivalent is [ajax](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

Code taken from the [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) example

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So you can send to it just any amount of data as you wish just that the client browser will swallow it slower and so, to overcome that you can do some serverside processing